# Increment and bitwise shift operator precedence?

Tags: c++

Increment suffix and prefix are both of higher operator precedence than bitwise left shift, but the following prints out different results.

```
int testValue = 1;
std::cout << ++testValue; //prints 2
//saw it as std::cout << (++testValue);

testValue = 1;
std::cout << testValue++; //prints 1
//thought it was std::cout << (testValue++);
```

Why does increment suffix as shown in the second example print 1 before incrmenting? I thought it was bound more tightly to `testValue` like in the increment prefix case, so I thought it'd be incremented first before being printed with `std::cout`.

Comment: There is no bitwise shift in this code

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Oh, I thought the `<<` operator was bitwise shift. What is it actually?

Comment: @DragonautX: You are correct. It is the left bitwise shift operator. Sami may have been referring to the fact that you are using an overloaded version of the operator which doesn't perform a shift, but that's not relevant. You never said it does do that. You named the operator correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` not bitwise operator, but `insertion operator`. [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) reference:

> As an object of class ostream, characters can be written to it either
>   as formatted data using the insertion operator (operator<<).

```
testValue = 1;
std::cout << testValue++; //prints 1
```

**Post increment** means the increment is done after the variable is read.

Comment: `<<` is, in fact, the left bitwise shift operator. It can be overloaded to do other things, but it is still the left bitwise shift operator. More importantly as far as this question is concerned, its precedence is the same no matter what you overload it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what `testValue++` does.

It increments `testValue` but its evaluation is before the increment is made.

The line

```
std::cout << testValue++;
```

is equivalent to

```
std::cout << testValue;
testValue = testValue + 1;
```